# add new layouts for RTL smartphones

Tags: android, android-studio

in android studio, when i'm coding a application, i use a lot of layout for english layout, actualy for LTR, how can i add new layouts for RTL smartphones?
because in smartphones that their language is designed for RTL user, my buttons and textviews and their location will change!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Add this in manifestif your application is willing to support right-to-left (RTL) layouts. The default value of this attribute will be false.

This if set to

true-various RTL APIs will be activated and used by the system so your app can display RTL layouts.

false- layout direction associated to the user's Locale choice (your layouts will always be left-to-right).

For more info check this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Also check this link for tutorial of ltr and rtl layouts

https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2